# bootstrap dropdown layout not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am facing layout issue in dropdown list,here is my Code

```
<li class="dropdown col-md-1">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Select Courses <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
   <select  name="selectVal">

                    <?php
                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"call courses_dropdown()");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                        {   

                            echo "<option value='" . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?> 
                </select>

</ul>
    </li>
```

Current result:
[image: current result is]

Wanted result:
[image: but i want result like this]

i mean i don't want nested dropdown as shown in image

Comment: just to give a quick thought, i think ur missing the class `form-control`

Comment: What is exactly that you want? A nicer looking dropdown? The "select course' option to be there?

Comment: you can see in first picture,when i click first dropdown then another dropdown opens,i want to avoid this ,just want single dropdown like 2nd image

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the css class "form-control" to your select.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option class="form-control" value='" . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] . "</option>";
```

use this to get your desire result.